# Data passing issue in Vue, with template tag and computed attribute

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify to build my project, I met an error when I'm trying to access the property in `computed`. Here's my code

```
    <v-stepper
      v-model="currentStep"
      :vertical="true"
      :alt-labels="false"
    >
      <template>
        <template v-for="n in ageStepsArray.length">
          <v-stepper-step
            :key="`${n}-step`"
            :complete="currentStep > ageStepsArray[n-1]"
            :step="ageStepsArray[n-1]"
          >
            {{ageStepsArray[n-1]}} years old
          </v-stepper-step>
          <v-stepper-content
            :key="`${n}-content`"
            :step="ageStepsArray[n-1]"
          >
            <v-list
              flat
            >
              <v-list-item-group
                v-model="settings"
                multiple
              >
                <v-list-item v-for="(item,index) in dreamList" :key="index">
                  <template v-slot:default="{active}">
                    <v-list-item-action class="pt-1">
                      <v-checkbox v-model="active"></v-checkbox>
                    </v-list-item-action>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                      <v-list-item-title>{{item.title}}</v-list-item-title>
                      <v-list-item-subtitle>
//error occurs here     Estimated cost: {{item.cost}} // want to change to getCostList[index].cost here
                        <v-btn icon x-small @click.stop="editValue(item)">
                          <v-icon >mdi-pencil-circle-outline</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>  
                      </v-list-item-subtitle>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                  </template>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list-item-group>
            </v-list>
            <v-btn
              color="primary"
              @click="nextStep(ageStepsArray[n-1])"
            >
              Continue
            </v-btn>
          </v-stepper-content>
        </template>
      </template>
    </v-stepper>

    /// script
    computed:{
      ...mapGetters({
        getCostList: "listCost/getList",
      }),
    }
```

Error:
Property or method "getCostList" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

I can access getCostListoutside the `v-stepper` successfully, and I've googled a lot for the solution, it seems to be related to the scope of `template` tag, but I found little result about this kind of issue.

I wonder if I'm using the wrong way to call the "getCostList" or there are other ways to resolve the error.

Comment: I notice you've called it both `getCostList` and `getCostlist` in your question.  Using the wrong one of those in your template would throw that same error if the computed had a different name...

Comment: That's my bad, I've checked the spelling again, and they're ```getCostList``` but still got the same error.

Comment: You probably need to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get some help with this.  Eliminate all the unnecessary stuff from this code including variables that we can't see.  And/or if possible post a reproduction at the problem at https://jsfiddle.net or https://codesandbox.io

Answer (score -1):

You didn't provide your complete script part thats why can't really say, but this is the most basic answer, i can write at the moment.

```
data() {
  return {
     // Define here
     getCostList: ''; //for Example
  };
},
```

Comment: Wasn't me, but probably because there is already a computed called `getCostList`.  Declaring a data variable of the same name is unnecessary and would throw an error.  And it would also not explain why the `computed` was undefined in the template.

Comment: And ```mapGetters``` is the helper that maps store getters to local computed properties